# Laravel not performing job queue with database

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5

I am trying to perform a job queue to execute mail and sms functioning in background process. And it is working with

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

in `.env` file
But when i use it with database

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

its not working even after using cli command:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Please tell me what is the problem with such functionality

laravel.log:[image]

Comment: Can you show at least some part of `storage/logs/laravel.log`, please?

Comment: i am adding that in my question as a image

Comment: Thanks. However it's too small portion of log and isn't related to queues. Could you please post full log to gist.github.com or pastebin.com?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/manish4926/523febfec5ae191bf8357a591d8338b9

Comment: you have jobs table?is it empty?

Comment: no...its not empty

Comment: can u post the screenshot of your table?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/hbmS4

Comment: $job = (new AfterPlaceOrder($orderid,$user->email))->delay(60 * 1);
        $this->dispatch($job);

Comment: dont know ! what's the problem is. It is clearly sending with QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

Comment: as you can see that your job have tried to execute for 165 times... do one thing try composer dump-autoload maybe it solve your error.. than run queue:listen

Comment: still not working..any other option

Comment: are you using supervisor?

Comment: Give as last log messages after your code exec please

Comment: Thanks Guys! it works now. It was a problem of using Eloquent query in Job page

Answer (score 1):

here is how i would debug it:

- stop supervisor if you are using it.
- cd into your directory and type php artisan queue:listen if you see any errors then likely you have some issues with the job class that you are running laravel 5.2 give you the path in the error and if you look closely you can see in the database the parameters that were passed to the constructor.

also check to see if the reserved field in the jobs table is filled, and the attempts are more than 1.

if the attempts are 0 that means you have a problem with your supervisor service (if you are using it) try unlink /path/to/socket.sock and then run the supervisord command.